# Close windows 8 warning/error overlays using the keyboard

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, mouse

How can I close / interact with popus / overlays like the following using only the keyboard?

[image]

It seems you can only close it with a mouse which is not always very practical.

Comment: Is the Virtual Keyboard not available for this case..

Comment: @Sant14: what? I want to do this using the hardware keyboard

Comment: @houbysoft you cannot tab to highlight the close button, then hit enter?

Comment: @Moab: first thing I tried...

Comment: @houbysoft you might consider posting all the things you have tried in your question, that we we don't have to guess or assume.

Comment: how about alt+f4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press and release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you will then be able to tab around the various interactive controls.
[image: keyboard nav]

Answer (score 2):

This is a setting that must be implemented or overridden by the application.

The Microsoft [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868161.aspx) says the following about his subject.

> Ensure that UI elements that can be clicked can also be invoked by
> using the keyboard. To use the keyboard with a UI element, the element
> must have focus. Only classes that derive from Control support focus
> and tab navigation.
>
> For UI elements that can be invoked, implement keyboard event handlers
> for the Spacebar and Enter keys. This makes the basic keyboard
> accessibility support complete and enables users to accomplish basic
> app scenarios by using only the keyboard; that is, users can reach all
> interactive UI elements and activate the default functionality.
>
> In cases where an element that you want to use in the UI cannot have
> focus, you could create your own custom control. You must set the
> IsTabStop property to true to enable focus and you must provide a
> visual indication of the focused state by using the VisualStateManager
> class. However, it is often easier to use control composition so that
> the support for tab stops, focus, and Microsoft UI Automation peers
> and patterns are handled by the control within which you choose to
> compose your content.

We can conclude 3 things

1. The UI element must have focus
2. The app can override the default and make it impossible to support the keyboard
3. Accessibility is relevant, if you could press enter then the app would not have accessibility support. And we know there is accessibility support in Windows.

We know that the application has accessibility support. Try to search for some of these options.

Comment: This is most certainly not an application setting, it's the system alert. Same thing appears ex. when you download a file it thinks is a virus, etc.

Comment: right, but then how do I control it? I tried everything I could think of (tab, esc, win-key, space, enter, ...)

Answer (score 0):

try

Windows+ctrl+B:Acces the Program that is displaying the message in the Notification area.

Win+Z: Get to app options

Check if it helps u in any way..

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately...